# Rails 4 - Can't get users to correctly join an event as a participant

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I think it's in my controller logic somewhere, just cannot figure it out. When I click join event, I cannot get the participant_id to go into the event so I can use event.participants in my view. I can create the event just fine and get the host to work fine, it's just the participants.

I will show my relationships, which I believe are OK.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_many :events_participants, foreign_key: :participant_id
    has_many :events, through: :events_participants
    has_many :hosted_events, class_name: "Event", foreign_key: :host_id
    has_one :workplace

    validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
end
```

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events_participants
  has_many :participants, through: :events_participants
  belongs_to :host, class_name: "User"

  validates :spots, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  validates :title, presence: true, allow_blank: false
  default_scope -> {order(time: :asc)}
end
```

events_participant.rb

```
class EventsParticipant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
end
```

Here are my controllers:

events_controller.rb

```
class EventsController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create,:update]
  before_action :find_event, only: [:show,:update,:edit,:destroy]

  def create
      @event = Event.new(event_params.merge(host_id: current_user.id))
      @event.save
      redirect_to root_path
  end

  def index
      @events = Event.all
  end

  def update
      @event.update_attributes(event_params)
      redirect_to @event
  end

  def destroy
      @event.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
  end

private

  def find_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:time, :title, :spots, :host_id)
  end
end
```

participants_controller.rb

```
class ParticipantsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
      participant = current_user
      event.participants << current_user
      redirect_to event
    end

    def destroy
      EventsParticipant.where(event_id: params[:event_id], participant_id: params[:id])[0].destroy()
      redirect_to Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end
end
```

This is what is showing up in the terminal when i click "join event"

```
 SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "events_participants" ("event_id", "participant_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["event_id", 12], ["participant_id", 2], ["created_at", "2015-04-01 18:45:34.458668"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-01 18:45:34.458668"]]
```

(14.0ms)  COMMIT

So, I can see it is inserting a participant_id that is equal to the current_user's ID into EventParticipants table, but I cannot figure out how to put that all together.

Comment: In ParticipantsController#Create, it does not appear you are saving the event object you've updated since there is no```event.save```  Might need to see the HTML you are triggering for this action since you have two separate controller actions that seem to be unrelated.  Does event.participants get made in the Event controller action?  If so then you'll need to include those params in ```event_params``` as well.

Comment: I think Im just over complicating it and confusing myself with the namespacing. Event.participants never actually gets created. An event is created first of all with a host. Then there is a button for other people to be able to join that event at a later time.

Comment: I recommend adding the pry gem to development, and opening a ```binding.pry``` session inside the code triggered for the join action (which I assume is EventParticipantsController#Create) to test if your syntax is working, particularly this flow: ```event = Event.find(params[:event_id])```, 
      ```participant = current_user```, and ```event.participants << current_user```  That syntax looks right, but I'm nearly positive that the ```<<``` syntax in rails does not actually cause the changes to your objects to persist unless you call ```event.save``` after.

Comment: You may be right. I will give that a try tomorrow as I unfortunately do not have my comp with me.